# How to rename the currency code to the full name of the currency? Swift

Tags: swift, string, nslocale

I created this method. I have an array of currency code. But when I insert a code, for example: “USD”, the method returns me Optional (“US dollar”). And whenever I try to extract an option, I get a nil. What did I do wrong?

```
func getCurrencyFullName(code: String) -> String? {
    let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: code)
print(locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: code) // Optional "US dollar"
    return locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode, value: code)
}

let dollar = getCurrencyFullName(code: UAH) 
print(dollar) // nil
```

Comment: BTW - don't use `NSLocale`. Use `Locale`.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a locale from a currency code? A currency code isn't specific to one locale. Use the user's current locale.

Comment: @rmaddy I receive API data with an array of currency codes and I need to change it to the full name of the currency. How to did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are trying to create a locale from a currency code and then you try to use that invalid locale to translate the currency code into a name. Just use the user's current locale to convert the currency code.

You should also use `Locale` instead of `NSLocale`.

```
func getCurrencyFullName(code: String) -> String? {
    return Locale.current.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: code)
}
```

In an English locale, this gives "Ukrainian Hryvnia" for UAH. In a Ukrainian  locale, this gives "українська гривня".

Answer (score 1):

Use Locale instead of NSLocale

```
  func getCurrencyFullName(code: String) -> String? {
        let locale1 = Locale(identifier: code)
        return locale1.localizedString(forCurrencyCode: code)
    }
```

it is help you.